# WordPress nav_menu - Filter output with conditional statement by Menu Name?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, menu

I'm using the **Dynamic Menus** within WordPress as a **widget**.  I'm trying to filter the output so that I can add a class to the `<a>` tags (not the parent `<li>` as is default) without relying on jQuery.

I do *not* want to filter by `theme_location` since I am switching the menu depending on page and cannot assign multiple dynamic menus to one location.

I'd like to target these menus by **Menu Name**.

So far i've come close by realizing what the available arguments are for `wp_nav_menu` found in the response to this question : https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/53950/add-a-custom-walkter-to-a-menu-created-in-a-widget

The following seems to be working fine:

```
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items','replace_class', 10, 2);

function replace_class($items, $args) 
{
    if ($args->menu->term_id == '27') {
            $items = preg_replace('/<a/', '<a class="custom-class"', $items);
        }

    return $items;

}
```

However this is only by using the "term_id" for the menu.

Trying to do something like:  `if ($args->menu == 'menu-services') {` for whatever reason does not work.  Could I be using the wrong filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

****UPDATE****

If you want to use your method or function - just add `slug`

```
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items','replace_class', 10, 2);

function replace_class($items, $args) 
{
    if ($args->menu->slug == 'your-menu-name') {
            $items = preg_replace('/<a/', '<a class="custom-class"', $items);
        }

    return $items;

}
```

**Original Answer:**

I answered this yesterday - see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23325379/add-custom-classes-to-wordpress-navigation-anchor-tags-not-lis/23330954#23330954)

Based on the [link](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/53950/add-a-custom-walkter-to-a-menu-created-in-a-widget) you provided (from wordpress stackexchange)
add this code to add a custom walker to your widget menu:

```
function widget($args, $instance) {
    // Get menu
    $nav_menu = ! empty( $instance['nav_menu'] ) ? wp_get_nav_menu_object( $instance['nav_menu'] ) : false;

    if ( !$nav_menu )
        return;

    $instance['title'] = apply_filters( 'widget_title', empty( $instance['title'] ) ? '' : $instance['title'], $instance, $this->id_base );

    echo $args['before_widget'];

    if ( !empty($instance['title']) )
        echo $args['before_title'] . $instance['title'] . $args['after_title'];

    wp_nav_menu( array( 'fallback_cb' => '', 'menu' => $nav_menu ) );

    echo $args['after_widget'];
}
$defaults = array( 'menu' => '', 'container' => 'div', 'container_class' => '', 'container_id' => '', 'menu_class' => 'menu', 'menu_id' => '',
'echo' => true, 'fallback_cb' => 'wp_page_menu', 'before' => '', 'after' => '', 'link_before' => '', 'link_after' => '', 'items_wrap' => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
'depth' => 0, 'walker' => '', 'theme_location' => '' );

$args = wp_parse_args( $args, $defaults );
$args = apply_filters( 'wp_nav_menu_args', $args );
$args = (object) $args;
function myplugin_custom_walker( $args ) {
    return array_merge( $args, array(
        'walker' => new Class_Name_Walker(),
        // another setting go here ... 
    ) );
}
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_args', 'myplugin_custom_walker' );
```

then add this walker - which adds the classes to the `a`

```
class Class_Name_Walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu
    {
        /**
         * Start the element output.
         *
         * @param  string $output Passed by reference. Used to append additional content.
         * @param  object $item   Menu item data object.
         * @param  int $depth     Depth of menu item. May be used for padding.
         * @param  array $args    Additional strings.
         * @return void
         */
         function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {
        $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '';

        $class_names = $value = '';

        $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;
        $classes[] = 'menu-item-' . $item->ID;

        $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item, $args ) );
        $class_names = $class_names ? ' class="' . esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"' : '';

        $id = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_id', 'menu-item-'. $item->ID, $item, $args );
        $id = $id ? ' id="' . esc_attr( $id ) . '"' : '';

        $output .= $indent . '<li' . $id . $value .'>';

        $atts = array();
        $atts['title']  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? $item->attr_title : '';
        $atts['target'] = ! empty( $item->target )     ? $item->target     : '';
        $atts['rel']    = ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? $item->xfn        : '';
        $atts['href']   = ! empty( $item->url )        ? $item->url        : '';

        $atts = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', $atts, $item, $args );

        $attributes = '';
        foreach ( $atts as $attr => $value ) {
            if ( ! empty( $value ) ) {
                $value = ( 'href' === $attr ) ? esc_url( $value ) : esc_attr( $value );
                $attributes .= ' ' . $attr . '="' . $value . '"';
            }
        }
        $item_output = $args->before;
        $item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .$class_names.'>';
        $item_output .= $args->link_before . apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ) . $args->link_after;
        $item_output .= '</a>';
        $item_output .= $args->after;

        $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
    }

    /**
     * @see Walker::end_el()
     * @since 3.0.0
     *
     * @param string $output Passed by reference. Used to append additional content.
     * @param object $item Page data object. Not used.
     * @param int $depth Depth of page. Not Used.
     */
    function end_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
        $output .= "</li>\n";
    }
    }
```

In your admin area go to Appearance > Menus.
On the top right of the screen click on 'Screen Options' on the bottom row - make sure 'CSS Classes' is checked.

Comment: Hi @Mark, as mentioned I am using the Menus dynamically through widgets- which doesn't seem to have a straight-forward approach to apply a custom walker to.

Comment: @Joe I updated my answer based on the link you provided

Comment: Unfortunately this destroys other walkers that are utilized for other menus.  (I have a few other dynamic menus hard-corded into the site, which use varying walker setups).  

Is there any reason why we cannot do a conditional based on Menu Name?

Comment: Very cool, that is exactly what I was looking for.  Whether or not this is a good practice, I have no idea.  

Where did you find that $args->menu->slug ?  I haven't seen any documentation for targeting that.

EDIT:  "The menu that is desired; accepts (matching in order) id, slug, name"

Comment: its in the get_term_by args [CODEX](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_by#Return_Values)